# Redirect non-www to www on nginx server

Tags: nginx

I want to redirect from https://example.com to https://www.example.com. I read multiple questions here and articles about how to do it but it doesn't seem to work. Here is what I tried:

```
server{
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

I set an A record with Name www that points to my IP.

I also use Cloudflare if that is important to know ...

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have your `/etc/init.d/nginx restart` ?

Comment: Did you check in an Incognito window? Many people make that mistake and get served with a cached version of the website

Comment: Yes and yes. After all I put a Rule in Cloudflare and it worked.